# How can I convert videos for Sony Xperia U on my Linux box?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, mp4, flv, mencoder

I would like to send a few videos for my girlfriend, but I would ensure they are playable on her mobile phone. I want to carry out the encoding tasks on my Arch Linux box, because my PC is a low end. I can use only ffmpeg or mencoder or other CLI tool. She can play youtube videos but I don't want to upload such videos to youtube. Are there any presets for specific mobile phones? And when she simply clicks a video direct link will it play directly on the cellphone or should I embed it in a html5 / flash player, like on youtube?

Answer (score 2):

## What the device supports

According to the [Xperia U White Paper](http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/st25/whitepaper_EN_st25_xperia_u.pdf) this device can decode H.264 video, High profile, level 3.2 in MP4 container with AAC audio.

## Example `ffmpeg` command

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -profile high -level 3.2 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -codec:a aac -strict experimental out.mp4
```

## What these options do

- `-codec:v libx264` – Choose video encoder `libx264` to encode H.264 video.
- `-crf 23` – Output video quality level. `23` is the default and a lower value is a higher quality.
- `-preset medium` – Encoding speed vs compression efficiency tradeoff. Default is `medium`.
- `-profile high` – Sets H.264 video profile to High.
- `-level 3.2` – Sets H.264 video level to 3.2.
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` – `ffmpeg` attempts to minimize or avoid chroma subsampling (depending on input, encoder, `ffmpeg` version, etc). This is technically a good thing, but can result in an output that non-FFmpeg based players can't handle. This ensures a compatible chroma subsampling scheme.
- `-movflags +faststart` – Relocates the "moov atom" to the beginning of the file so playback may begin before the file is completely downloaded in the case of progressive download (such as watching via a browser).
- `-codec:a aac -strict experimental` – Encode AAC audio using the experimental native FFmpeg AAC encoder. It's not the worst AAC encoder, but if it sounds shitty use a higher bitrate with `-b:a` (default is 128k).

## Additional notes

- Use a recent version of `ffmpeg`. Old versions do not enforce the correct number of reference frames when using `-level` (fixed [bug #3307](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3307)), but since you're using Arch Linux you don't need to worry about that.
- The ffmpeg package from the Arch Linux Extra repository only supports the native FFmpeg AAC encoder. Recompile from ABS with `--enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree` (with libfdk-aac package as a depends) or use the ffmpeg-git package in AUR to gain support for encoding with libfdk_aac which is the best AAC encoder supported by FFmpeg. Using the ABS package is recommended over the AUR package if you want to try this.
- If the input video and/or audio is already compatible then you can simply [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) it instead of re-encoding, such as with `-codec:a copy`.
- The mobile device may have additional restrictions that I am unaware of, so you will have to experiment. I'm also unsure if the device will work with a plain link to the video, but that would be easy to test.
- See the [FFmpeg H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [FFmpeg AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for additional info.

Comment: @Konstantin Did this example work for you?